# How do Equally Sized Spheres Fit into Space?

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

How much volume do spheres take up when filling a rectangular prism of a shape?

I assume it's somewhere in between $\frac{3}{4}\pi r^3$ and $r^3$, but I don't know where.

This might be better if I broke it into two questions:

First: How many spheres can fit into a given space? Like, packed optimally.

Second: Given a random packing of spheres into space, how much volume does each sphere account for?

I think that's just about as clear as I can make the question, sorry for anything confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read a lot about these questions [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing).

Concerning the random version, there are some links at [Density of randomly packing a box](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56123/density-of-randomly-packing-a-box). The accepted answer links to a paper that "focuses on spheres".

Comment: Note that the [Kepler conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture) claims the optimum density (ratio of spheres' total volume to space filled) can be attained in either of two packings.  This optimum density (approaching $\pi/\sqrt{18}$ for increasingly large "rectangular prism" to fill, or increasingly small spheres) does not depend on radius(?) $r$ in the way OP's question suggests.

Answer (score 0):

There are some links [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/index/52-XX.html) (Rusin's known-math site). Also [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/spherepack.html) (Eppstein's Geometry Junkyard).